# MySQL query works in version 5.6 but returns errors in mysql version 8

Tags: mysql, reserved-words

I am not SQL expert therefore am scratching my head why this query would not work in MySQL-community-server 8.0 but it works absolutely fine in MySQL 5.6.

I have recently migrated from mysql 5.6 to version 8.0. Maybe I have missed something.

See below.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO images(SystemRoot, BaseBuildRevisionNumber, BuildBranch, BuildGUID, BuildLab, BuildLabEx, CompositionEditionID, CurrentBuild, CurrentBuildNumber, CurrentMajorVersionNumber, CurrentMinorVersionNumber, CurrentType, CurrentVersion, EditionID, EditionSubManufacturer, EditionSubstring, EditionSubVersion, InstallationType, InstallDate, ProductName, ReleaseId, SoftwareType, UBR, PathName, ProductId, DigitalProductId, DigitalProductId4, PendingInstall, DisplayVersion, InstallTime, Software, System, Manufacturer, Model, Systype, Serial, HDD1, HDD2, HDD3, HDD4, Partitions, OurParts, Date, Time, FileName, CurrentOperation, Progress, Status, TotalParts, CurrentPartition, DiskRead, DiskWrite, NetBandwidth, NetUp, NetDown, CPU, PartitionType, PartitionDetails, ImageByParts, ImageFileNames) Values ("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "UEFI", "Dell Inc.", "Latitude 3510", "Notebook", "BFVS303", "128 GB", "None", "None", "None", "sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6", "1", "2023-11-10", "18:32:57", "Dell_Inc._Latitude_3510_Notebook_wj2GQdFq", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "gpt", "1", "True", "Dell_Inc._Latitude_3510_Notebook_wj2GQdFq-sda1.img.gz");
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'System, Manufacturer, Model, Systype, Serial, HDD1, HDD2, HDD3, HDD4, Partitions' at line 1
```

However, if I run the exact same query in mysql 5.6 it works fine, see below.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO images(SystemRoot, BaseBuildRevisionNumber, BuildBranch, BuildGUID, BuildLab, BuildLabEx, CompositionEditionID, CurrentBuild, CurrentBuildNumber, CurrentMajorVersionNumber, CurrentMinorVersionNumber, CurrentType, CurrentVersion, EditionID, EditionSubManufacturer, EditionSubstring, EditionSubVersion, InstallationType, InstallDate, ProductName, ReleaseId, SoftwareType, UBR, PathName, ProductId, DigitalProductId, DigitalProductId4, PendingInstall, DisplayVersion, InstallTime, Software, System, Manufacturer, Model, Systype, Serial, HDD1, HDD2, HDD3, HDD4, Partitions, OurParts, Date, Time, FileName, CurrentOperation, Progress, Status, TotalParts, CurrentPartition, DiskRead, DiskWrite, NetBandwidth, NetUp, NetDown, CPU, PartitionType, PartitionDetails, ImageByParts, ImageFileNames) Values ("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "UEFI", "Dell Inc.", "Latitude 3510", "Notebook", "BFVS303", "128 GB", "None", "None", "None", "sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6", "1", "2023-11-10", "18:32:57", "Dell_Inc._Latitude_3510_Notebook_wj2GQdFq", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "gpt", "1", "True", "Dell_Inc._Latitude_3510_Notebook_wj2GQdFq-sda1.img.gz");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Maybe someone expert with databases and mysql queries can help me spot the error.

Comment: `System` is a reserved word in MySql 8.03+:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-S

Comment: so put backticks around it

Comment: @user2107349 If the backticks worked for you, please give ysth a left click reply above with the uparrow.  Just so we know you are good to continue with your project.

Comment: Yes the backticks around system worked. Thanks for the help.